# My method for comparing DateTime doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

So, I'm making a small version of library inventory manager. I have a method that should call the database, take one DateTime values and compare it with today's date. I have a table with rented books and in every row there is a "rented_till" value. My loop should go through every row and my method should compare those values. The problem is that it doesn't work and even my flags are not working

I tried to use breaking points but even their I can see that compailer skips my code.
This is something new for me, since I never done that some maybe I'm doing something completley wrong. I couldn't find a similary problem. You can see my method below.

```
    public void CheckBooks()
    {
        OverdueBooksDAL obDAL = new OverdueBooksDAL();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = obDAL.RentedBooks();
        int rows = dt.Rows.Count;
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            DateTime rented_till = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["rented_till"]);
            int result = DateTime.Compare(today, rented_till);
            if (result > 0)
            {
                OverdueBook OB = new OverdueBook();
                OB.Id = Int32.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString());
                OB.Title = dt.Rows[i]["title"].ToString();
                OB.Rented_Till = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["rented_till"]);
                string fullname = dt.Rows[i]["name"].ToString() + dt.Rows[i]["surname"].ToString();
                OB.Rented_By = fullname;
                OverdueBooksDAL obeDAL = new OverdueBooksDAL();
                if (obeDAL.InsertOverduebooks(OB))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There are new books overdue");
                }
            }
        }
```

Program compiles and every other part of it works. I've checked the tables and they're getting the data from the data base.

Comment: Any reason you are converting the date? What is the date stored as in the database?

Comment: `DateTime.Compare(today, rented_till);` What is the **exact** value of `today`? `rented_till`? What does `Compare` return?

Comment: Not sure if is intended or not: `DateTime.Compare` returns `0` if they are equal, and negative or positive if they are not. You are ignoring `result < 0`

Comment: It's stored as a DateTime but when I tried to assign it to the value it didn't work I had to convert it.

Comment: rented_till is a DateTime value which is set to the 01/01/2019, today is a DateTime value which is set to today's date which is 06/01/2019.
If the rented_till will pass the today then the loop shoul execute as intended and I can even see in the debuger that it is "true" but program skips the code inside of the loop.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` does include the hour, minutes and seconds. Maybe you want to use `DateTime.Today` to have better match if your database only includes the date and not the time.

Comment: Please check the values of both variables I mentioned in the `Immediate Window`. Please paste their values into your question itself.

Comment: It's easier/note logical to use < and > to compare times, viz: `if(DateTime.UtcNow > rented_till)`. Use UTC if storing dates in a db

Comment: Also I note that you Convert.ToDatetime your query result; please tell me you're just doing this to cast, and not because in your db your dates are stored as strings? Dates should be used throughout. Casting with (DateTime) is easier/less wordy than Convert. The concern I have with your dates if they're strings is that "06/01/2019" could be the 6th Jan or the 1st Jun, only one of these is overdue

Comment: If the debugger skips code when it shouldn't (for example you can see that `result > 0` is `true` but it doesn't go into the inner code, it is usually because the code is from a different project that hasn't been rebuilt since it was changed. i.e. you're still running the old code, while looking at the new code.

Comment: Okey guys, it's been a while. I recreated entire project and now it works. I was not able to find the issue so I still wonder what happend but it works!
@CaiusJard No, I store my dates us a datetime, the thing is that their not recognize as a datetime object so I need convert them one more time to datetime.

Comment: If you store your data as a datetime, and you need to use Convert.ToDateTime then either you've done something that causes them to be selected as a string, or it's just that in a weakly typed datatable the column type might well be datetime, but asking a datarow for its ["columnname".Value returns an object and this needs casting. I'd need to see a screenshot of your locals window showing an expanded .ItemArrray property to know for sure